# Getting selected dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I've got a number of drop downs on a page that filter a list.  However, when I try to get those values within a function I get nothing returned every time!

I've tried the following: -

```
var browserVal= document.getElementById("browser").options[document.getElementById("browser").selectedIndex].value;
var browserVal= document.getElementById("browser").options[document.getElementById("browser").selectedIndex].text;
```

I've also tried: -

```
systemVal = $("#browser").children("option").filter(":selected").val();
systemVal = $("#browser").children("option").filter(":selected").value;
systemVal = $("#browser").children("option").filter(":selected").text();
```

As well as: -

```
var browserVal= $("#browser").text()
var browserVal= $("#browser").val()
```

The items are setup like so: -

```
<fieldset class="buttons">
system   
<select id="System" class="filterField" name="System" style="width:250px">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="3">Processing</option>
<option value="2">Other</option>
<option value="1">Reporting</option>
</select>
Browser   
<select id="browser" class="filterField" style="width:175px" name="browser">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="IE">IE</option>
<option value="RND">RND</option>
<option value="FF">FF</option>
<option value="CH">CH</option>
</select>
</fieldSet>
```

Any suggestions to alternatives that I could try I'm out of ideas as an identical approach on a different page works fine... :S

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions but I've tried them all and none of them are working. Not sure why I've been voted down either I'm not sure what else I can say I've done or tried at this stage, nothing appears to be working...

Comment: It would seem there were bigger issues and when I fixed those all was working again.  So apologies for the stupid question all and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get selected value of drop down like this

```
var dropDown=document.getElementById("browser");
var selectedValue=dropDown[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
```

Similarly You can do This to get text

```
var e = document.getElementById("browser");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
systemVal = $("#browser").find("option:selected").val();
```